# Integrated webcam worked on previous version, but not Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, webcam

My camera has not been working for a while, but I remember that it worked before (on the first version that I used (not sure whether it was 19.04 or 19.10)). My current version is 20.04 LTS.

Actually it wasn't important for me because I didn't use the camera at all, but now I'm in need of the webcam.

This is the `lsusb` output:

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 8087:0a2a Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 044: ID 1bcf:28c1 Sunplus Innovation Technology Inc. Integrated_Webcam_HD
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 2a7a:8a4f  CASUE USB KB
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

and `dmesg` output:

```
[ 5332.180445] input: Integrated_Webcam_HD: Integrate as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-5/1-5:1.0/input/input67
[ 5570.253427] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: Enabling HDA controller
[ 5570.377637] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: bus: MMIO read of 00000000 FAULT at 6013d4 [ IBUS ]
```

I found another error about my webcam:

```
[ 5330.924694] input: Integrated_Webcam_HD: Integrate as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-5/1-5:1.0/input/input66
[ 5331.659970] usb 1-5: USB disconnect, device number 43
[ 5331.660554] uvcvideo: Failed to resubmit video URB (-19).
[ 5331.664522] uvcvideo: Failed to resubmit video URB (-19).
[ 5331.668522] uvcvideo: Failed to resubmit video URB (-19).
[ 5331.672556] uvcvideo: Failed to resubmit video URB (-19).
[ 5331.676522] uvcvideo: Failed to resubmit video URB (-19).
[ 5332.000022] usb 1-5: new high-speed USB device number 44 using xhci_hcd
[ 5332.156460] usb 1-5: New USB device found, idVendor=1bcf, idProduct=28c1, bcdDevice=65.05
[ 5332.156466] usb 1-5: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[ 5332.156470] usb 1-5: Product: Integrated_Webcam_HD
[ 5332.156473] usb 1-5: Manufacturer: CN0WNTY0LOG0077BBC5KA01
```

And here is cheese output:

```
** (cheese:11738): CRITICAL **: 11:38:32.294: cheese_preferences_dialog_setup_resolutions_for_device: assertion 'device != NULL' failed
```

and also an error with guvcview:

```
V4L2_CORE: (VIDIOC_DQBUF) Unable to dequeue buffer: No such device
```

What could be the problem, and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue and a simple restart solved it. If that doesn't work, try installing guvcview from snap store.

```
sudo snap install guvcview
```

Worked like a charm for me.

Comment: Hi thanks to reply but it didn't work for me, i put the errors with running cheese and guvcview